# How to echo the literal "-n"

Tags: bash, echo

Is it possible to echo the two-character string `-n` using just the `echo` command built into the `bash` shell?

I know I can do `printf '%s\n' -n` but was just wondering if the `echo` built-in is capable of outputting the string `-n` at all.

Comment: Covered pretty nicely in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549

Comment: I'm not sure what to think about this question. I mean, you already know the practical solution is to use `printf`, and you probably also know the background about the portability issues with `echo` in general (the things mentioned in Jeff's link). So, what's left here then? Just an exercise in doing things the hard way, or finding the exact limits of suck in a thing you know sucks? Any result you get is going to be specific some shell or shells anyway, exactly because the behaviour of `echo -n` is so hideously non-portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `-e` and octal 55 for the `-`:

```
$ echo -e '\055n'
-n
```

... or octal 156 for the `n`, or octal for both:

```
$ echo -e '\055\0156'
-n
```

If the `-e` is bothering you, set the shell option `xpg_echo` to make `echo` always interpret backslash sequences (this is not usually what you want though):

```
$ shopt -s xpg_echo
$ echo '-\0156'
-n
```

The `echo` in `bash` also recognizes hexadecimal:

```
$ echo -e '\x2d\x6e'
-n
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. I'll add one of my own that I've just thought of:

```
echo -n -;echo n
```

Answer (score -1):

Put any character before the "`-n`", and use the "`\b`" escape sequence in `-e` mode to erase it in the final output. The below example uses a space for the dummy character:

```
$ echo -e " \b-n"
-n
```

Explanation:

```
$ man echo
       If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
       \b     backspace
```

This works visually for printing output to the terminal:

```
$ echo -e " \b-n" | tee /tmp/test
-n
$ cat /tmp/test
-n
```

But you may run into problems if you need to parse the output, as it does produce an invisible backspace character:

```
$ echo -e " \b-n" | wc -c
5
$ wc -c <<< $(echo -e " \b-n")
5
$ echo -e "--" | wc -c
3
```

Comment: But with ` \b-n` the output is not the two bytes `-n` (dash and lowercase letter n). For outputs that are similar-looking but not really the same, you could also use `echo "-n "`. The trailing white space would be less likely [citation needed] to cause issues than a surprise backspace.